# using nginx to serve angular-seed basic project

Tags: angularjs, nginx, ngroute, nginx-location, angular-seed

I've cloned the Angular-seed project, ran it with npm install and npm start, and everything worked just fine.

Then I wanted to use a different web server, not the dev one that comes with npm, but the production one, to see if I can configure the angular seed basic state (view1, view2) to work with nginx.
I've had some nginx.conf file for a different project someone I know is working on, and I took it and tried to make it work.
It serves the index.html just fine, but when I try to switch to view2 or view1 (from the partial views) - I get nothing. it navigates to the right address (I see it updates the address to #/view1 ) but the content stays the same.
this is the conf file:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    # Frontend root folder
    root /myapp/app;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;

    }
}
```

the structure of angular-seed can be found here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

I know this is probably basic, but i've tried different conf files and nonthing works.
I know that the order of the files in the location block is ok, and I know that it supposed to serve everything - but still nothing.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with conf file, it must have angular route installed, which is in app.js, and view1 and view2 folder which needs a template path , which has nothing with backend except serving..

Comment: See this https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/view1/view1.js

Comment: it is installed. so I'm not sure what else do I need to change in my code.

Comment: Are you using nodejs to run the server?

Comment: no, just nginx.
I'm guessing there's something basic that I'm missing here.

Comment: Was missing some deps. everything works now. thanks.

Comment: Cool , all the best